# Java double losing precision

Tags: java, excel, double

I have a series of calculations using doubles in Java that should always add up to 1.0. Occasionally, in Java the sum is off a little. I perform the calculations in Excel, and they do add up to 1.0. I suspect this has to do with some double rounding errors. What has me puzzled is that it works in Excel. Any idea what I can do to fix this?

I have the following code in Java:

```
  double d1 = 0.979;
  double d2 = 3;
  double d3 = 21;
  double d4 = d1 * d2 / d3;
  System.out.println("d4 " + d4);
```

That prints 0.13985714285714285. In Excel, if I do the same calculation `(=C14*D14/E14)` where C14 is d1, D14 is d2, and E14 is d3, I get 0.1398571428571430000. Is Excel getting this right because it is rounding?

Thanks.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic has its limitations, and I suspect this question has been asked before on SO.  You could try using `BigDecimal` if you really need such precision.

Comment: `double` in Java is inherently imprecise. Use `BigDecimal` whenever  precision is required.

Comment: Both Java and Excel are rounding for this one - the mathematically correct result is an infinite repeating decimal.

Comment: Any ideas on why Excel is rounding differently (and in this case, getting the answer "correct")?

Comment: As @Douglas points out, neither are mathematically correct. But on the subject of floating point, please familiarize yourself with the inherent precision issues, e.g. by reading http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Why do you think Excel's answer is "correct"?  Those trailing 0's at the end look suspicious.  Any time you divide an integer (or a number with a terminating decimal) by 7, you'll get 142857 in a repeating pattern.

Comment: @ajb Exactly true.  And in Excel VBA, that calculation, using the Decimal data type (shows value to 28 decimals) returns (with spaces to show the repeat):  ` 0.139857 142857 142857 142857 1429`
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it with BigDecimals. Although a Java double is not a precise way to work with decimal fractions, it is still quite accurate and certainly more accurate than Excel.

And with BigDecimal you can control the rounding yourself, and also work with decimal fractions rather than binary fractions, giving you a more intuitive result if you're used to working in decimal.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal d1 = new BigDecimal("0.979");
    BigDecimal d2 = new BigDecimal("3");
    BigDecimal d3 = new BigDecimal("21");
    BigDecimal d4 = d1.multiply(d2.divide(d3, MathContext.DECIMAL128));
    System.out.println("d4 " + d4);
}
```

Output:

```
d4 0.1398571428571428571428571428571428991
```

Comment: Why do you say that Java is "more accurate than Excel"? Excel is using `double` math too, it is just showing too many decimals.

Comment: @Andreas I was referring to the OP's displayed result from Excel which is less accurate than Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to round the result to 15 decimal places you can do

```
double d1 = 0.979;
double d2 = 3;
double d3 = 21;
double d4 = d1 * d2 / d3;
double r15 = Math.round(d4 * 1e15) / 1e15;
System.out.println("r15 " + r15);
```

https://ideone.com/s0mT72 prints

```
r15 0.139857142857143
```

which is the number you get in excel.